# Create non-optional in guard to test guarded condition

Tags: swift, guard

I currently have a function like this...

```
// this is a property
var currentString: String = ""

func doSomething() {
    let newString: String = goGetANewString()

    guard newString != currentString else {
        return
    }

    currentString = newString
}
```

But I find it a bit odd that I am creating the `newString` outside of the `guard`.

If I move it into the `guard` then it complains that it needs to be optional.

Is there a way of creating that `newString` inside the `guard` statement and checking the condition?

Ideally I'd like something like this, but like I said, it doesn't work this way.

```
func doSomething() {
    guard let newString: String = goGetANewString(), newString != currentString else {
        return
    }

    currentString = newString
}
```

Comment: Why does it feel odd to call `goGetANewString` before `guard`?

Comment: @user28434 because I'm only ever using the `newString` if the guard succeeds. By creating the `newString` before the guard I then also have access to it inside the `else` of the guard. Which is fine... if I need it. But in this case I specifically don't.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "trick" is to use `guard case` with a [value-binding pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH36-ID422) for the assignment:

```
func doSomething() {
    guard case let newString = goGetANewString(), newString != currentString else {
        return
    }

    currentString = newString
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I need to read up more about the different uses of `case`. I only really know/understand them inside switches.